# Hibernate collections with a table with no key column

Tags: hibernate

I have 2 tables one like this. I'm using hibernate version 3.6.5.

```
@Entity
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String userName;
    private List<String> costCenters;
}
```

I have another table like this:
TableUserCostCenter

```
username costcenter
user1    xxxx
user1    xxx1
user1    xxx2
user1    xxx3
user2    xxx3
user3    xxx3
user4    xxx3
```

I want my User to get a list with all the `costCenters` on a `userentity`. Is there any good way to do this with annotations on an entity?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the annotations http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection. They provide the annotation to map a collection.